# In the film In Time how do those under 25 pay for goods and services?

Tags: in-time

People in the film In Time don't receive a year of time currency (the only currency used) until their 25th birthday. How do they pay for goods and services before this, considering they have no currency to offer? Is there some sort of free allowance or do they rely on their parents for all of these things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though they don't go and directly say it, the children are dependent upon their parents for their survival. Until the clock starts, their time cannot be taken or used (though it can be gained). This was brought up when Justin Timberlake's friend drank himself to death, and his wife wondered how she was going to afford raising her child byself. It is also mentioned the first time you see the baby, with 'all its precious time' (a year). The little girl that Timberlake gives a minute is also collecting time for when she turns 25, foreseeing the fact that she's going to need that extra time.